# Java - Problem at sorting array list using bubblesort

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, arraylist, bubble-sort

I have a problem at the moment I have a college assignment and we need to list a file that contain books and should be sorted A to Z,

My sort algorithm is a bubble sort and at the moment is not sorting alphabetically but don't give errors, I cant see where I should change to make it work as the coding seems correct to me.

We are not allowed to use collections so that is the reason I am not using sort().

```
package Book;
public class AlphabeticalOrderTitle{
    //Global variables
    public static String input;
    public static int bookId;
    public static String bookTitle;
    public static String authorName;
    public static boolean isAvailable;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   
        ArrayList<Book> books = BubbleSort();
        System.out.println(linearSearch(books));
    }
    
    public static ArrayList<Book> loadData() {
        //Creating an array list;
        ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
        
        try {
            //Here we start reading our file
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Book.txt"));
            
            //This header string will allow to skip the header so does not mismatch with getter and setters.
            String header = br.readLine();
            
            //This string will read the lines.
            String contentLine = br.readLine();
            
            //Giving our array name data;
            String [] data;
            
            //Here we loop to continue the reading of data for each array box.
            while (contentLine != null) {
                

                data = contentLine.split(",");
                bookId = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
                bookTitle = data[1];
                authorName = data[2];
                isAvailable = Boolean.parseBoolean(data[3]);
                books.add(new Book(bookId, bookTitle, authorName, isAvailable));
                contentLine = br.readLine();
            }
            
        }catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SearchBookAuthor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,ex);
        }       
        return books;
    }
    
    public static int linearSearch(ArrayList<Book> array){
        
        //Variables for holding values
        int n;
        String temp;
        
        // Going one by one the elements in the array
        for(int g = 0; g < array.size(); g++){
            
                //Getting the array size from the file and giving the array name a size
                  n = array.size();
                  String names[] = new String[n];
                
                //Load all the names
                  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                      names[i] = array.get(g).getBookTitle();
                  }
                  
                  //Bubble sort starts
                  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
                  {
                      for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) 
                      {
                          if (names[i].compareTo(names[j]) > 0) 
                          {
                              temp = names[i];
                              names[i] = names[j];
                              names[j] = temp;
                          }
                      }
                  }
                 //Print sorted
                    System.out.println(names[n-1]);
               
            
        }      
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Outpout:

```
Captains
Romeo
Don
-1
```

and what I am aiming is Captains, Don, Romeo.

My book.txt contains is like this:
[book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVuh3.png)

Any suggestion for me to fix it ? Thank you very much.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS it does happen in the `linearSearch` method

Comment: HINT: A correct bubble sort doesn't need **three** levels of loop nesting, only _two_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a couple days working on it I have come with a working solution thanks to everyone.

```
public class Alphabetical_Order {

//Global variables
public static String input;
public static int bookId;
public static String bookTitle;
public static String authorName;
public static boolean isAvailable;

//Creating an array list;
public static ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    loadData();
    int n = 0;
    String temp;
  //Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter number of names you want to enter:");
    
    //get size of arraylist
    for (int g = 0; g < books.size(); g ++) {
           n = books.size();

    }
    
 
    String names[] = new String[n];
    
    //Names to be get from user
    Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter all the names:");
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        names[i] = books.get(i).getAuthorName();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) 
        {
            if (names[i].compareTo(names[j])>0) 
            {
                temp = names[i];
                names[i] = names[j];
                names[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.print("Names in Sorted Order:");
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) 
    {
        System.out.print(names[i] + ",");
    }
    System.out.print(names[n - 1]);
}

public static void loadData() { 
    
    try {
        //Here we start reading our file
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Book.csv"));
        
        //This header string will allow to store the header so does not mistach with getter and setters.
        String header = br.readLine();
        
        //This string will read the lines.
        String contentLine = br.readLine();
        
        //Giving our array name data;
        String [] data;
        
        //Here we loop to continue the reading of data for each array box.
        while (contentLine != null) {
            
            data = contentLine.split(",");
            bookId = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
            bookTitle = data[1];
            authorName = data[2];
            isAvailable = Boolean.parseBoolean(data[3]);
            books.add(new Book(bookId, bookTitle, authorName, isAvailable));
            contentLine = br.readLine();
        }
        
    }catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SearchBookAuthor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,ex);
    } 

    
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Bubble Sort Example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/)

I linked a bubble sort example. You can click on Java to see a version in Java. And you can see there are differences between yours and theirs, even though they are very similar.

What I would do is do it manually. That is, grab some paper, write down what your array looks like then actually pretend you're the computer and see what you end up with. It will be a good exercise for you, and you'll probably figure out what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, BubbleSort() is not an appropriate name for this method as all it does is reading the file and storing the content inside the list.

If this course is not an upper-level algorithms class, you could probably use java libraries to sort your list instead.

Something like this should work and produce the needed result:
Collections.sort(books);

Also, I usually just do the following:
**List** books = new ArrayList<>();

In case you have to implement bubble sort, please use the following link which shows how to use bubble sort to sort string arrays: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-strings-using-bubble-sort-2/

Comment: It is an upper-level and I changed the name method as was confusing, we are not allowed to use collections

Comment: Yep, then just use the following link to bubble sort the array of strings:  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-strings-using-bubble-sort-2/

Comment: You could just convert your list to an array as well before using the above code: String[] booksArray= books.toArray(new String[0]);

Answer (score 0):

For array A of 'n' elements A[n], then the first loop in bubble sort always ends with n-1.
The idea of bubble sort is to compare the adjacent elements and then swap if the are not in order (increasing / decreasing depending on the use case).

So, when i=n-1, as you mentioned in your first for loop=>j=n-1. We are basically comparing A[i=n-1] to A[j=n-1].

```
//Bubble sort starts
                  for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) 
                  {
                      for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) 
                      {
                          if (names[i].compareTo(names[j]) > 0) 
                          {
                              temp = names[i];
                              names[i] = names[j];
                              names[j] = temp;
                          }
                      }
                  }
```

you can try a quick dry-run whenever you are stuck in such problems by substituting with small numbers and writing the loop content on paper. Helps a lot to learn and to build logic. :)

Comment: Perfect, understood the logic behind it will use all the comments and answers in my favor, thanks everyone.